Add-Member with Pipeline-Iteration not assigning Member
I want a new property called “ID” to be added to each object in the pipeline. I use Add-Member for this. Strangely, however, “Out-Gridview” does not output an ID property. Even the selection of “Select-Object” is not displayed in “Out-GridView”.
$itemsInDownloadFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\$Env:USERNAME\Downloads"
$itemsInDownloadFolder | Select-Object -Property FullName, LastWriteTime, Path, Length, ID | ForEach-Object -Begin {
                                            [Int]$IDNumber = 1
                                            $numberOfItemsInDownloadFolder = $itemsInDownloadFolder.Count
                                            $itemsToDelete = @(1..$numberOfItemsInDownloadFolder)
                                            
                                        }`
                                         -Process {
                                            $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ID" -Value ($IDNumber++) -Force
                                           
                                         }`
                                         -End {
                                            $itemsInDownloadFolder | Out-GridView
                                            $itemsNotToDelete = @((Read-Host "ID der nicht zu löschenden Dateien/Ordner (z. B.: 1, 3, 6)") -split ",")
                                            $itemsToDelete = $itemsToDelete | Where-Object { $_ -ne $itemsNotToDelete }
                                            ForEach($value in $itemsToDelete) {
                                                $itemsInDownloadFolder[$value] | Remove-Item
                                            }
                                         }
                                         
                                             
                                            


                                                                           

I tried to add the parameter “-PassThru” or a variable that should save the objects again. Here is an example (did not work):
$itemsInDownloadFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\$Env:USERNAME\Downloads"
$itemWithID = $itemsInDownloadFolder | Select-Object -Property FullName, LastWriteTime, Path, Length, ID | ForEach-Object -Begin {
                                            [Int]$IDNumber = 1
                                            $numberOfItemsInDownloadFolder = $itemsInDownloadFolder.Count
                                            $itemsToDelete = @(1..$numberOfItemsInDownloadFolder)
                                            
                                        }`
                                         -Process {
                                            $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ID" -Value ($IDNumber++) -Force -PassThru
                                           
                                         }`
                                         -End {
                                            $itemsWithID | Out-GridView
                                            $itemsNotToDelete = @((Read-Host "ID der nicht zu löschenden Dateien/Ordner (z. B.: 1, 3, 6)") -split ",")
                                            $itemsToDelete = $itemsToDelete | Where-Object { $_ -ne $itemsNotToDelete }
                                            ForEach($value in $itemsToDelete) {
                                                $itemsInDownloadFolder[$value] | Remove-Item
                                            }
                                         }
                                         
                                             
                                            


                                                                           


Select-Object -Property ... creates new objects, so you're adding the ID member to those new objects, NOT the original objects stored in $itemsInDownloadFolder. Additionally, why not let the user select the items in the gridview that they want to preserve, rather than asking for a list of IDs?

Hey! Thank you very much for your answer. If you don't mind me asking: How can I let the user select something in the gridview?
